# JQuery replace two table rows based on the data attribute of one

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table in which I have editable data. Each 'editable' section covers two table rows.

```
<table>
    <tr data-doc_id2='doc_id2'>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr data-doc_id2='doc_id2'>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr data-doc_id2='doc_id2'>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr data-doc_id2='doc_id2'>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
</table>
```

(Please note I haven't put the `<td></td>` in....)

My jQuery so far is as follows. This will replace the first row with the relevent ID. I am having trouble selecting the second row... `next()` seems to be looking for the next row that has the ID.

```
 var new_row="<tr data-doc_id2='"+doc_id+"'>
    <td>"+doc_name+"</td>
    <td>"+first_ins4+"</td>
    <td>"+job_price4+"</td>
    <td>"+tender4+"</td>
    <td><a class='edit_docs' href='javascript:void(0);'>Edit</a> | <a class='del_doc' href='javascript:void(0);'>Delete</a></td>
 </tr>";
    var new_row2="<tr><td colspan='4'>"+second_ins4+"</td><td></td></tr>";

    var row_to_change=$("tr:[data-doc_id2='"+doc_id+"']");
    $(row_to_change).replaceWith(new_row);
```

Comment: You've swapped the `-` and `_`, added a `2`, and prepended a `:` to the selector, but that shouldn't select the first row either.

Comment: Sorry - the html was more of an example html as the original table is dynamically generated... I will look at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var row_to_change=$("tr:[data-doc_id2='"+doc_id+"']");
 $(row_to_change).closest('tr').next('tr').remove();
 $(row_to_change).replaceWith(new_row);
```

Instead of having new_row and new_row2 I stuck the HTML together in new_row variable replacing one of the rows with the two new rows then removed the next row by using a standard selector. Clumsy but works.

Comment: If `row_to_change` is a `<tr>`, then you don't need `.closest("tr")`.